# How to convert the J axiom to the fixed-argument form?

Tags: agda

I was trying to prove that `true ≡ false -> Empty` assuming the `J` axiom. It is defined as:

```
J : Type
J = forall 
  {A : Set} 
  {C : (x y : A) → (x ≡ y) → Set} → 
  (c : ∀ x → C x x refl) → 
  (x y : A) → 
  (p : x ≡ y) → 
  C x y p
```

My attempt went like this:

```
bad : J → true ≡ false -> Empty
bad j e = j Bool (λ { true _ _ => Unit; false _ _ => Empty }) _
```

Now, to proceed with the proof, I needed a term `c : ∀ x -> C x x refl`. Since I instantiated `C`, it becomes `c : ∀ x -> (λ { true _ _ => Unit; false _ _ => Empty } x x refl`. Then I got stuck. `c` can't reduce further because we don't know the value of `x`. I wasn't able to complete this proof. But there is a different version of `J`:

```
J' : Type
J' = forall 
  {A : Set} 
  {x : A}
  {C : (y : A) → (x ≡ y) → Set} → 
  (c : C x refl) → 
  (y : A) → 
  (p : x ≡ y) → 
  C y p
```

With this one, this problem is solved, because `t` can be fixed to be `true`. This makes the `c` argument reduce to `Unit`, which we can provide. My question is: can we convert the former version to the later? That is, can we build a term `fix_x : J → J'`? Does that hold in general (i.e., can indices be converted to parameters)?

Comment: The different version of `J` does not type check. Is the second `x` argument redundant?

Comment: @user3237465 my bad, it had an additional `x`, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, regarding `true ≡ false -> Empty`: this is unprovable if you can only eliminate into `Set0` with `J`, so you need an universe polymorphic or large definition. I write some preliminaries here:

```
{-# OPTIONS --without-K #-}

open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Level

data Bool : Set where true false : Bool
data Empty : Set where
record Unit : Set where
  constructor tt

JTy : ∀ {i j} → Set _
JTy {i}{j} =
  {A   : Set i}
  (P   : (x y : A) → (x ≡ y) → Set j) →
  (pr  : ∀ x → P x x refl) →
  {x y : A} →
  (p   : x ≡ y) →
  P x y p

J : ∀ {i}{j} → JTy {i}{j}
J P pr {x} refl = pr x

J₀ = J {zero}{zero}
```

Now, `transport` or `subst` is the only needed thing for `true ≡ false -> Empty`:

```
transp : ∀ {i j}{A : Set i}(P : A → Set j){x y} → x ≡ y → P x → P y
transp P = J (λ x y _ → P x -> P y) (λ _ px → px)

true≢false : true ≡ false → Empty
true≢false e = transp (λ {true → Unit; false → Empty}) e tt
```

---

Considering now proving the pointed `J'` from `J`, I know about three solutions, and each uses different features from the ambient theory.

The simplest one is to use universes to abstract over the induction motive:

```
JTy' : ∀ {i j} → Set _
JTy' {i}{j} =
  {A  : Set i}
  {x  : A}
  (P  : ∀ y → x ≡ y → Set j)
  (pr : P x refl)
  {y  : A}
  (p  : x ≡ y)
  → P y p

JTy→JTy' : (∀ {i j} → JTy {i}{j}) → ∀ {i}{j} → JTy' {i}{j}
JTy→JTy' J {i} {j} {A} {x} P pr {y} e =
  J (λ x y e → (P : ∀ y → x ≡ y → Set j) → P x refl → P y e)
     (λ x P pr → pr) e P pr
```

If we only want to use a fixed universe level, then it is a bit more complicated. The following solution, sometimes called "contractible singletons", needs `Σ`-types, but nothing else:

```
open import Data.Product

JTy→JTy'withΣ : JTy {zero}{zero} → JTy' {zero}{zero}
JTy→JTy'withΣ J {A} {x} P pr {y} e =
  J (λ {(x , r) (y , e) _ → P x r → P y e})
    (λ _ px → px)
    (J (λ x y e → (x , refl) ≡ (y , e))
       (λ _ → refl)
       e)
    pr
```

There is a solution which doesn't even need `Σ`-s, but requires the beta rule for `J`, which says that `J P pr {x} refl = pr x`. It doesn't matter whether this rule holds definitionally or just as a propositional equality, but the construction is simpler when it holds definitionally, so let's do that. Note that I don't use any universe other than `Set0`.

```
transp₀ = transp {zero}{zero}

transp2 : ∀ {A : Set}{B : A → Set}(C : ∀ a → B a → Set)
        {x y : A}(e : x ≡ y){b} → C x b → C y (transp₀ B e b)
transp2 {A}{B} C {x}{y} e {b} cxb =
  J₀ (λ x y e → ∀ b → C x b → C y (transp₀ B e b)) (λ _ _ cxb → cxb) e b cxb

JTy→JTy'noΣU : JTy' {zero}{zero}
JTy→JTy'noΣU {A} {x} P pr {y} e =
    transp₀ (P y) (J₀ (λ x y e → transp₀ (x ≡_) e refl ≡ e) (λ _ → refl) e)
      (transp2 {A} {λ y → x ≡ y} P e pr)
```

Philosophically, the third version is the most "conservative", since it only assumes `J`. The addition of the beta rule is not really an extra thing, since it is always assumed to hold (definitionally or propositionally) for `_≡_`.

> can indices be converted to parameters?

If you have propositional equality, then all indices can be converted to parameters, and fixed in constructors using equality proofs.

Comment: Damn, that first proof is so clean and obvious I feel bad for not realising it. Thanks for all the alternatives. Do you chance offer consulting? I'd really like to have your thoughts and insights about a specific language. Would it be possible for me to reach you directly?

Comment: @MaiaVictor reddit is fine